# VBA to C++ dll function call, how to have missing argoument

Tags: c++, function, vba, dll

I have function that I compiled with C++ as dll. I access it via vba no problem everything works great.

I want to have one of the arguments to be set to a specific value if the user does not specify its value. I dont know how to do it ,

I tried 
double __stdcall h2e_q_DLL (double & t, double & qi, double & d1, double & n, double & df, double & qa, double & up =1.0 )

last value "up" to be set to 1.0 but...

i get this: 1>c:\users\alex\documents\c++\h2e_project\v2\test\main.cpp(8) : error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'double &'

i tried searching for a solution but could not find anything, anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy I'm afraid. The optional argument has to be a VARIANT. See Microsoft docs for details on this structure.

On the C / C++ side, you check the vt field of the variant structure which will be set to the missing type if a value has not been passed. At this point you can do your defaulting logic.

On the  Vba side you declare the argument as optional byref variant.

You might be able to supply a default value here ; I'm on the train so can't check.

You'll have fun extracting the data out of the variant; use the vt flag to check th type before extracting the data.

Comment: Thanks Bathsheba, I am not a power C++ user can you help me by walking me through it?

Comment: double __stdcall h2e_q_DLL (double & t, double & qi, double & d1, double & n, double & df, double & qa, double & up  )

Comment: It is pretty tough and I don't have a C compiler at home to test stuff. Why not cheat? Don't have the optional argument at all in the interface function but have a stub function in vba that supports the optional parameter which calls the interface one with the default value injected. Will be much easier for you to maintain this and as you grow in confidence you can explore handling other data types. Cunning plan no?